# Get specific line from db's text type field

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have made a **table** in my **database**, which table contains a **text type field**. Within this field there are **ten lines** which correspond to **ten different values**. What I want to do for example, is to call this field (I have already done this) but I want to get **only the fifth line**! Or each line separately anyway... Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any more certain way to address that line other than "fifth line"? An identifier? A some certain value?

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, this does not smell good. It sounds a lot like your data is not normalised and you'd make life a lot easier if you did separate the delimited values...

...HOWEVER I know all too well that sometimes it's just not possible. I frequently have to deal with this kind of thing (thanks to decisions made using legacy technologies being perpetuated beyond my control).

If you too are stuck with someone else's design decision, this should do the trick:

http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

---

EDIT: Downvote without a comment? Nice...

Comment: Wasn't mine... I never downvote people who spent their time to answer to me, even if their answer isn't what I want!

Answer (score -1):

That's easy.
You need to create **another table** linked to this one.
And have ten different records in this new table corresponding to one record in your old table.

This is how databases work.

Comment: There is a table in my database that contains a text type field and in to this field you can find values like this [link](http://img853.imageshack.us/img853/2861/oa2.png).

Comment: Yes. That's what a new table I am talking about for.

Comment: I think you don't understand what I want to do... Every value has something after "=". I want to take this part of text, after "=" or the whole line! To help you understand, they are joomla's parameters.

Comment: Your Common Sense you are out of the subject